# Get value from input within slot Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've tried to get data from my child component `Dropdown.vue` which inside this component contain `slot` for `input` value searching

```
.ui-dropdown__nav(ref="dropdown" :style="styles")
  .ui-dropdown__search-box(v-if="$slots['search-box']")
    slot(name="search-box")
  ul.ui-dropdown__menu
    li.ui-dropdown__item(
      v-for="(item, index) in options"
      :key="index"
      :class="{ 'ui-dropdown__item--current': label === item }"
    )
      button.ui-dropdown__choose(@click.prevent="$emit('change', item, index)")
        | {{ item }}
```

and this is my `parent` component

```
 ui-dropdown(
   :options="infoOptions"
   :label="selectedInfo ? selectedInfo : 'Select'"
   @change="selectInfo"
 )
   ui-input(
     small
     slot="search-box"
   )
```

how can I get value from input to pass for a child component. Thanks

Comment: If you just want to pass data like objects and strings use [`props`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html). Slot is more used for if you want to pass HTML to a component

Comment: Hi, @JesseRezaKhorasanee Thanks for the answer. does that mean it's impossible if I still using a slot?

Comment: It's entirely possible using slot. It's more verbose than what's needed for sending text to a component. You'll love how much easier to think about props are.

Comment: If you upload full versions of your .vue files I'm sure someone here could help

Comment: Thanks, now I use props instead of slot

Comment: wohooo glad it worked